# Server-side copy on SMB share via command line

Tags: terminal, command-line, copy-paste, smb

I need to copy a large number of files and folders from one folder to another on the same SMB share exposed by an Isilon server featuring server-side copy. Copying individual files and folders through the Finder window works fine, almost instantaneously, and does not cause any significant network traffic, thus I assume that here server-side offloading works. However, when I try to copy files from the terminal, my network traffic goes up and the throughput is accordingly low.

The share is mounted as follows:

```
$ mount
//my.name@server/RemoteFolder on /Volumes/RemoteFolder (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by my.name)
```

I tried to copy via the command line using `cp`, `scp`, `ditto`, and `rsync` to no avail, e.g.,

```
$ cp -vpRi "/Volumes/RemoteFolder/old/Peter Gabriel/" "/Volumes/RemoteFolder/groups/genesis/peter.gabriel"
```

How can I imitate the behaviour from option-drag & drop through the Finder in the command line?

Grateful for any hints!

Comment: Are you sure that Findet actually *copies* (duplicates) the files and doesn't just move them?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Both `CMD+C`/`CMD-V`ing as well as option-drag copies a folder I use for testing with about 300 MB in a few seconds, while `cp` et al. takes almost one minute.

Comment: Are you using `SMB2` to mount and have you tried scopy from smbclient? And https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Server-Side_Copy

Comment: I ended up using robocopy from a Win10 host - thanks @Trefex for the link to the samba doc.